# If there's an empty value for a key in JSON, send error status (AJAX, Node and Express)

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

Here's the flow I'm trying to achieve:

- Use AJAX to send object to Node / Express server
- Server-side, `JSON.stringify` the object in the request data
- **This is the important piece:** If the value of the `"task"`key is empty / false (i.e. ""), send a response status client-side (e.g. `res.sendStatus(403)`)

  - Issue is that the server-side `if` block (indicated by a comment below) doesn't get run

Client-side AJAX post (main.js):

```
$.post("/add-tasks", userToDo);
```

userToDo object being sent server-side:

```
userToDo = {
task = string;
important = boolean;
urgent = boolean;
quadrant = int; // 1 - 4
}
```

Example stringified JSON:

```
{"task":"","important":"true","urgent":"false","quadrant":"2"}
```

Server-side JS (app.js) -- the important snippet is denoted by a comment:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var fs = require("fs");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(`${req.method} request for '${req.url}' - ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);
    next();
});

app.use(express.static("./public"));

app.post("/add-tasks", function(req, res) {

    // ********* HERE **********
    if ( !JSON.stringify(req.body["task"]) ) {
        res.sendStatus(403);
    } else {
        fs.appendFile("tasks.json", JSON.stringify(req.body));
    }

});

app.listen(3000);

console.log("Express is running on port 3000");
```

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify` in that test? It will convert an empty string to a string that contains `""` which is not false. Just test `if (!req.body.task)`...

Comment: @jcaron Ah, thank you! Makes total sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!req.body["task"]) {
    res.sendStatus(403);
} else {
    fs.appendFile("tasks.json", JSON.stringify(req.body));
}
```

```js
var your_object = {"task":"","important":"true","urgent":"false","quadrant":"2"};

console.log(!JSON.stringify(your_object["task"]));

var your_object = {"task":"hello","important":"true","urgent":"false","quadrant":"2"};

console.log(!JSON.stringify(your_object["task"]));


var your_object = {"task":"","important":"true","urgent":"false","quadrant":"2"};


console.log(!your_object["task"]);


var your_object = {"task":"hello","important":"true","urgent":"false","quadrant":"2"};

console.log(!your_object["task"]);
```